# How to set the IntellIJ's scala format for if statement?

Tags: scala, if-statement, intellij-idea, scala-3

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2 (Community Edition, Build #IC-222.4167.29) with Scala plugin 2022.2.677.
I want the scala if statement with following style:

```
class test {
    def ifelse(i: Int): String =
        if i == 1 then "one"
        else if i == 2 then "two"
        else if i == 3 then "three"
        else "many"
}
```

But it was formatted by IDEAIJ as following:

```
class test {
    def ifelse(i: Int): String =
        if i == 1 then "one"
        else if i == 2 then "two"
             else if i == 3 then "three"
                  else "many"
}
```

I can not found an option to change this.

Comment: Try to disable the option `Align if-else statements` under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Scala | Wrapping and Braces | if() statement`

Comment: It works. thanks @EgorKlepikov very much. I did not find it myself because the example of this option is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable the option `Align if-else statements` under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Scala | Wrapping and Braces | if() statement`